# xlsread in octave return zero values

Tags: octave

I am trying to read a csv file in octave. The file contains a table with both numeric and text data. It also contains information of date and hour. In addition, the first line is in a different format then the rest of the lines since it contains titles.
The csvread can only read numeric data (according to Octave help), so I tried using xlsread as follows:

[NUMARR, TXTARR, RAWARR, LIMITS] = xlsread ('Line.csv')

I get only a matrix of NUMARR with numeric values. However, all other returned variables are empty- their dimension is 0x0.

How do I get all the text and all other information?

TX!

Comment: why do you think `xlsread` is a good candidate to read csv data? And it would be much easier if you verbatim add the first 5 lines of you file and not to try to describe it. Please see also how to create a MCVE

Comment: I agree, you should use `csvread('Line.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, open your CSV file in Windows notepad and save it as ANSI format instead of UNICODE.